# How can I construct this concept for my gallery?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically, I am trying to create a concept that I have designed into actual code, but I have gotten stuck. I want to construct this [creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBcOY.png). I have made the gallery with the pictures, but I am having some troubles producing the spacing, color underneath the picture, and caption. If I add a caption, all the images get spread out to where I don't what them to be. Could anyone please help me in creating this? All I need is the spacing, color, and caption to work, since the gallery itself is responsive. Any help is appreciated. Thanks. Here is my code so far. Click the "Full Page" link on the snippet.

```css
.intro {
    margin-top: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
  
  .gallery_container-all {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
  #outside{
      background-color: lightcyan;
  }
  .gallery_container {
    width: calc(33% - 6px);
    overflow: hidden;
    height: fit-content;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: black;
  }
  
  img {
    width: 100%;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .gallery_title {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 35%;
    display: none;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
  }
  
  .gallery_text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: none;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  
  .gallery_container:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  
  .gallery_container:hover span {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .intro {
      margin-top: 40px;
  }
  .gallery_container {
      width: 100%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
        <div id = "outside">
    <div class="intro">
        <h1>Earth</h1>
        <h4>Here are some pictures of Earth</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="gallery_container-all">
        <div class="gallery_container thefirst">
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5554114/pexels-photo-5554114.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="Image description goes here">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery_container">

        </div>
        <div class="gallery_container thesecond">
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4300360/pexels-photo-4300360.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="Image description goes here">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery_container thethird">
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4555540/pexels-photo-4555540.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="Image description goes here">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery_container">

        </div>
        <div class="gallery_container thefourth">
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5254697/pexels-photo-5254697.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="Image description goes here">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the `HTML` for the `caption` and the `orange line`?

Comment: That's what I need help creating. If I try to add a caption, the images spread out all over. Same thing for the red line.

Comment: Why have you added empty divs like this: `<div class="gallery_container"></div>`

Comment: For the images to have space, because if I remove them, there will be no space on the side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the work.

```css
.intro {
  margin-top: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.gallery_container-all {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 50px;
}

#outside {
  background-color: lightcyan;
}

.gallery_container {
  width: 60%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.gallery_container:nth-last-of-type(2n + 1) {
  justify-self: end;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  padding-top: 60px;
  background-color: lightcyan;
}

.content h3 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.content h3::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: orangered;
  border-radius: 500px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .gallery_container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="outside">
  <div class="intro">
    <h1>Earth</h1>
    <h4>Here are some pictures of Earth</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery_container-all">
    <div class="gallery_container thefirst">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5554114/pexels-photo-5554114.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="Image description goes here" />
      <div class="content">
        <h3>Caption </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="gallery_container"></div> -->
    <div class="gallery_container thesecond">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4300360/pexels-photo-4300360.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="Image description goes here" />
      <div class="content">
        <h3>Caption </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_container thethird">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4555540/pexels-photo-4555540.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="Image description goes here" />
      <div class="content">
        <h3>Caption </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="gallery_container"></div> -->
    <div class="gallery_container thefourth">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5254697/pexels-photo-5254697.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="Image description goes here" />
      <div class="content">
        <h3>Caption </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed.